# Run PHP script in Python 2.7

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am wondering how to execute a php code if a python statement is true.As an example I need to do something like this.I am using Python 2.7 because im sending an email using 2.7 libraries.This doesnt work,i've been writing on python for 2 days and i dont know much about it .It also gives me an error:

```
import subprocess
import os
a=input(" ")
if(a>0):
   subprocess.call(["php", "write.php"])

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\PROGRAMS\xamkpp\htdocs\proba.py", line 5, in <module>
     subprocess.call(["php", "write.php"])
   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
     return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
     errread, errwrite)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
     startupinfo)
 WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: it works then gives me an error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PROGRAMS\xamkpp\htdocs\proba.py", line 5, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["php", "write.php"])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: what does `which php` return?

Comment: Try using the full pathname of `php`, e.g. `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: the php file writes in a document

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre In Python 2 `input()` parses what you enter, so if you type a number it returns a number, not a string. You're thinking of `raw_input()`.

Comment: that's right. I forgot that. I _never_ use `input` in python 2.

Comment: @Barmar ye still the sam error

Comment: Is `/usr/bin/php` the correct path on your system?

Comment: nah man ,the both files are in the same folder

Comment: @Barmar: this is windows ("WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified"). I suppose that `php` is installed but not in Windows path. We make a good team tonight :)

Comment: @KoichoGeorgiev can you type `where php` ?

Comment: Oops, I don't know what the equivalent would be in Windows. The OP should be able to find the location on his system.